# Is there a way to have installed all the packages of a docker image in a specific directory?

Tags: docker, pycharm, dockerfile, gcloud

I'm trying to connect Pycharm to a docker container where gcloud is installed. In order to run my project I need to set the path where gcloud is installed.

1. Is there a way to have installed all the packages in a specific directory when creating a docker container?
2. If not, how can I look for the path where gcloud has been installed?

Edit, found answer for the second question:

After [entering in the container's shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-do-i-get-into-a-docker-containers-shell) is possible to find [where Google Cloud SDK is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33920484/find-out-where-google-cloud-sdk-is-installed).

Anyway, being able to install all the content of the docker image in a specific directory would be still preferable.

Comment: Usually, building a Python-based container, your Dockerfile would have something like `pip install -r requirements.txt`; that would install everything your application depends on in the "normal" paths, and package entry points for things like the `gcloud` command-line tool should be in the "normal" paths (maybe `/usr/local/bin`).

Comment: From what I see by default they are also installed in the "normal" paths as you said, I will try to work with them, thank you!